# Reading the child nodes from the root node

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to read the child nodes from the below xml and need to insert the data into database.

Am using the below line to select the child nodes from the root node but every time its reading the first application data.I know i have hardcoded the path in the below method but I am not sure how to read the child nodes one by one.

```
XmlNodeList boxNodeList = document.SelectSingleNode("applications/application/contacts").ChildNodes;
```

Sample XMl

```
    <applications>
     <application >
        <contacts>
           <business-owner>
              <a></a>
              <b></b>
              <c>  </c>
           </business-owner>
           <it-owner>
              <a></a>
              <b></b>
              <c></c>
           </it-owner>
           <architect>
              <a></a>
              <b></b>
              <c></c>
           </architect>
           <dataContact>
              <a></a>
              <b></b>
              <c></c>
           </dataContact>
           <technical>
              <a></a>
              <b></b>
              <c> </c>
           </technical>
           <technical>
              <a></a>
              <b></b>
              <c> </c>
           </technical>
           <other> </other>
        </contacts>
           </application>
     <application >
        <contacts>
           <business-owner>
              <a></a>
              <b></b>
              <c> </c>
           </business-owner>
           <it-owner>
              <a></a>
              <b></b>
              <c> </c>
           </it-owner>
           <technical>
              <a></a>
              <b></b>
              <c> </c>
           </technical>
           <other/>
        </contacts>

     </application>
     <application >
        <contacts>
           <business-owner>
              <a></a>
              <b></b>
              <c> </c>
           </business-owner>
           <it-owner>
              <a></a>
              <b></b>
              <c> </c>
           </it-owner>
           <other/>
        </contacts>

     </application>
     </applications>
```

Answer (score 0):

get contacts node nodes and then you can iterate each contacts node and get the child nodes as below

```
XmlNodeList nodes= document.SelectNodes("applications/application/contacts");
foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    XmlNodeList boxNodeList = node.ChildNodes;
    // do something with boxNodeList 
}
```